# TFS 2013 Shelve set build fails when shelve set contains new/added files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild

I have an unusual situation.  On TFS 2013 build environment, shelveset builds fail when the users shelveset contains added/new files.

1. The user creates a shelveset with the news files added and some
   changes to existing files.
2. User queues a build with the shelveset.
3. The build server creates a new workspace, merges the shelveset files
   and the added/new files all have "Warning: There are other pending
   changes against the item." in the build log.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this a lot when we were in TFS 2013. They seem to have fixed the issue in 2015 which doesn't help you now.

I seem to recall that we could work around the issue by shelving without preserving changes in the local workspace so that there aren't conflicting pending changes from TFS's point of view. You could restore the files to the local workspace by unshelving them after the build completes.

Comment: We have tried that but the developers don't like their changes disappearing from their local workspace and having to unshelve them again but it is an option.

Comment: So we have tried creating shelve sets with "Preserve changes locally" NOT slected and the build server still doesn't pull the changes into the build workspace.  I can login to the server as the build user, go to VS and open the same workspace used and the shelve set files unshelve successfully.